# How to make an order isomorphism

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, order-theory

Two linear orders $A$ and $B$ have starting points $a_0$ and $b_0$, and have cofinalities $\omega_1$. Let $(a_\alpha )_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ and $(b_\alpha )_{\alpha<\omega_1}$ be cofinal sequences.  Suppose we also know that for every $\alpha<\omega_1$ there is an order isomorphism $[a_\alpha ,a_{\alpha+1}]\simeq [b_\alpha ,b_{\alpha+1}]$ that maps $a_\alpha$ to $b_\alpha$ and $a_{\alpha+1}$ to $b_{\alpha+1}$.

Can we conclude that $A$ is isomorphic to $B$? How would you write this down?

Thank you for any help.

Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not true, because there may be elements of $A$ or $B$ that is in neither of the $[a_\alpha,a_{\alpha+1}]$ intervals.
For example, consider
$$A = \omega_1, \qquad a_\alpha=\alpha$$
and
$$B = \omega_2+\omega_1, \qquad b_\alpha=\begin{cases}\alpha & \alpha<\omega \\ \omega_2+\alpha & \alpha\ge\omega\end{cases}$$

Then clearly $[a_\alpha,a_{\alpha+1}] \simeq [b_\alpha,b_{\alpha+1}]$ simply because both intervals are always two-point sets. However, $A$ and $B$ don't even have the same cardinality, so they can't be order isomorphic.

Comment: I am very pleased that you found a counterexample!  You have no idea how helpful this was.  I thought I could just go along with a straight-forward induction routine, but you showed me what can go wrong at the limit ordinals ($\omega$ in your example). Fantastic!

Comment: So, I think you would need to ensure that if $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal the $b_\alpha$, $\alpha<\gamma$, limit to $b_\gamma$.  Then your example would not work because the $b$'s could not escape the $\omega_2$ segment.

Comment: @user160663: Yes, that might work. I think you'd still need some kind of choice principle for combining all of the local isomorphisms into a global one.