# Choosing elements of linear orders

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Is it consistent with ZF that there can be a countable family of linear orders, each isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ (that is, every element has a unique predecessor and successor, and any two elements have finitely many elements between them), such that one cannot choose an element from each of them?

(Random musing inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850735/how-to-make-an-order-isomorphism/850913#850913).)

Comment: Let $\{P_n: n \geq 1\}$ be a countable family of pairs of socks - So there is no set that contains exactly one sock from each $P_n$. Then $\{P_n \times Z: n \geq 1\}$ should work.

Comment: @hot_queen: So then what are the orderings?

Comment: @hot_queen: But you can't choose the ordering for these sets. If you could, you can choose from $P_n$ the element for which $(a,0)$ was smaller than $(b,0)$.

Comment: You guys are right. What I wrote is nonsense.

Comment: Is your statement equivalent to Countable Choice?

Comment: @Tom: Heavens no. It follows easily from the axiom of countable choice for families of countable sets. It is even weaker than "countable unions of countable sets are countable". By which I mean, of course the negation of the statement given here.

Comment: Ok, so it is weaker than CC$(\omega)$. Interesting that this is still independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is consistent. Let me sketch an argument using atoms, then the Jech-Sochor transfer theorem can do its magic (since it's a bounded statement).

Start with a countable set of atoms which is the disjoint union of $A_n$'s each countably infinite. Fix $\leq_n$ on $A_n$ which is a linear order of type $\omega^*+\omega$ (or $\Bbb Z$, in other words).

The automorphism group is $\mathscr G$, of permutations of the atoms which preserve both the partition into the $A_n$'s and their linear orders. In other words, we take a sequence of automorphisms of $\leq_n$ (which are finite shifts), and they each act on the relevant $A_n$. Let us denote a permutation by $\pi$ and $\pi_n$ is the permutation on the $n$-th coordinate.

We define a filter of subgroups in the following way. Given $H$ a subgroup of $\mathscr G$, $H$ is in the filter if and only if there exists a finite $E\subseteq\omega$, such that whenever $\pi\in\mathscr G$ for which $\forall n\in E$, $\pi_n=\operatorname{id}$, then $\pi\in H$. (For example taking $E=\varnothing$ we have that $\{\pi\in\mathscr G\mid\forall n\in\varnothing(\pi_n=\operatorname{id})\}=\mathscr G$ itself.)

Some easy propositions:

1. Each $A_n$ is symmetric, and each $\leq_n$ is symmetric.
2. The enumerated partition $\{A_n\mid n\in\omega\}$ is symmetric, and the enumeration of the orders is also symmetric.

And the important point: There is no choice function from the $A_n$'s.

Sketch for a proof: If $f$ was such a choice function, it would have a finite support $E$ as above, now taking any $k\notin E$ we can apply any $\pi$ which fixes $f$ but $\pi_k\neq\operatorname{id}$ to get a contradiction.

(This is the usual argument.)

---

Now we can use the Jech-Sochor theorem. Or we could have used forcing to begin with, it would just make things harder to write down properly in this case.

Comment: I'm afraid you lost me at "The filter of subgroups ..." Are you sure that sentence says what you meant it to? As written it looks like every subgroup $H$ meets the condition because we can take $E=\varnothing$ and then "for all $n\in E$" is vacuously true. (And where is $\pi$ quantified in this definition?)

Comment: Also, did I miss a definition of "symmetric", which you seem to apply to a lot of different things in the subsequent text?

Comment: @Henning: I sort of skipped the most of it; I'd thought that you know a bit more about the topic. In any case, here are [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28145/axiom-of-choice-and-automorphisms-of-vector-spaces/29469#29469) different [threads](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57871/proving-every-set-can-be-totally-ordered-without-using-axiom-of-choice/58384#58384) with the definitions. As for the empty case, note that if $E=\varnothing$ then it is necessarily the case that $H=\mathscr G$.

Comment: x @Asaf: Really? Take any odd $H$. Then there exists $E$ (namely $\varnothing$) such that $E$ is a finite subset of $\omega$ (yes, $\varnothing$ is a finite subset of $\omega$), and such that $\forall n\in E$ such-and-such holds (trivially because $E$ is empty).

Comment: Henning, I do not appreciate the tone of your text. I'm trying to answer and be helpful. And since we require that **ALL** the permutations $\pi$ such that $\pi_n=\operatorname{id}$, for all $n\in E$ this is necessarily means that **EVERY** $\pi\in\mathscr G$ satisfies this condition. So all in all, $H=\mathscr G$ (yes, double inclusion and whatnot).

Comment: a @Asaf: I'm not intending any tone. I'm trying to understand your helpful answer. I don't see how the choice $E=\varnothing$ fails make every $H$ satisfy your condition. Which of the two parts of it does it fail?

Comment: Let me rewrite this condition in the answer in a way which will be clearer.

Comment: x @Asaf: Okay, I read you original wording as "... and $\forall n\in E\;(\pi_n=\operatorname{id}\Rightarrow \pi\in H)$" which confused me.

Comment: @Henning: Fair enough. At least it's clear now.